# truffle command line version older than it is in package.json

Tags: truffle, installation

After installing Truffle with `yarn add truffle`, the following line shows up in `package.json`:

```
  "truffle": "^5.1.52"
```

In the root directory of the project, the `truffle version` prints out the following:

```
$truffle version
Truffle v4.1.12 (core: 4.1.12)
Solidity v0.4.24 (solc-js)
```

Why is the Truffle version from command line is one version older than it is in the `package.json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `truffle version`, you are asking for the version of your globally installed Truffle. You can run this command from any directory and you will get the same result.

To see the Truffle version of your project, you can run `npx truffle version`.